# How do I set up a success/failure block so that I can pass a string into it using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlrequest

I have an API method that returns teams for particular leagues. All I need to do is pass in some parameters.

For example, the API URL looks like this: http://api.website.com/api/teams?season=last&league=0Xc334xUK4

Here is my code:

```
@objc class APITeam: NSObject {

    var leagueObjectID: NSString!

    let baseUrl = "http://api.website.com/api"

    static let sharedInstance = APITeam()

    static let getTeamsEndpoint = "/teams"

    static let params = "?season=last&league="

    private override init() {}

    func getTeams (_ onSuccess: @escaping(Any) -> Void, onFailure: @escaping(Error) -> Void) {

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: baseUrl + APITeam.getTeamsEndpoint + APITeam.params)!)

        let session = URLSession.shared

        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data : Data?, response : URLResponse?, error : Error?) in

            if(error != nil){
                onFailure(error!)
            } else{

                do {

                    let result  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!)
                    onSuccess(result)

                } catch {

                    print(error)

                }

            }

        }
        task.resume()

    }

}
```

In order for this API method to return data, I need to pass in the objectID of the league I want teams for when making a request.

I've tried to add parameter to:

```
func getTeams (_ onSuccess: @escaping(Any) -> Void, onFailure: @escaping(Error) -> Void, leagueObjectID: String) {

 var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: baseUrl + APITeam.getTeamsEndpoint + APITeam.params + leagueObjectID)!)
```

This doesn't work as expected. When I use the method in another class, "leagueObjectID" acts as an additional part of the success, error block if that makes sense. I need to be able to pass the leagueObjectID into the method so it's used at the end of the URL the request is made to.

This is how I call APITeam in an objective-c class:

```
[[APITeam sharedInstance] getTeams:^(id result) {

} onFailure:^(NSError * error) {

}];
```

As you can see, the extra parameter I added to the getTeams function doesn't show up, and when I try to manually add it, I get an error.

How would you handle this?
An example would be much appreciated.

Thanks for your time

Comment: "When I use the method in another class" - edit your question to show this code; both the working original version and the failing version with the additional `leagueObjectID` argument. That will help people "make sense" of what you are describing and help you.

Comment: The idiomatic style would be to have a single closure as the last parameter.  Any other parameters would come before the closure parameter.  The single closure would be declared as (SomeType?,Error?); Then if the `Error` isn't `nil` you know there was an error.  This style allows you to use a trailing closure on the function invocation.

Comment: @CRD The bottom of my question shows what I tried to do. I felt it would be better not to paste the whole block of code again.

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm going try this out now.

Comment: @LondonGuy - Unless I'm misunderstanding, or wasn't clear, "the bottom of your question" shows how you changed the definition of `getTeams` and not how you are creating an `APITeam` instance and calling `getTeams` "in another class" which is when you say you get a problem.

Comment: @CRD I've updated my question now.

Comment: "As you can see, the extra parameter I added to the getTeams function doesn't show up, and when I try to manually add it, I get an error." - This sounds like Xcode getting out of sync with itself. The common fix for this is to do a `Clean Build Folder` (hold down option key and click the `Project` menu to see this menu item) followed by a project rebuild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
@objc class APITeam: NSObject {

    var leagueObjectID: NSString!

    let baseUrl = "http://api.website.com/api"

    static let sharedInstance = APITeam()

    static let getTeamsEndpoint = "/teams"

    static let params = "?season=last&league="

    private override init() {}

    func getTeams (leagueObjectID: String, _ onSuccess: @escaping(Any) -> Void, onFailure: @escaping(Error) -> Void) {

        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: baseUrl + APITeam.getTeamsEndpoint + APITeam.params + leagueObjectID)!)

        let session = URLSession.shared

        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data : Data?, response : URLResponse?, error : Error?) in

            if(error != nil){
                onFailure(error!)
            } else{

                do {

                    let result  = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!)
                    onSuccess(result)

                } catch {

                    print(error)

                }

            }

        }
        task.resume()

    }

}
```

Then in my Objective-C class:

```
[[APITeam sharedInstance] getTeamsWithLeagueObjectID:@"93PwHe5e4S" :^(id league) {
    NSLog(@"THE LEAGUE: %@", league);
} onFailure:^(NSError * error) {

}];
```

It's also important to build the app before trying to access the original class. That was a vital step for me. Sometimes I don't need to do this, but this time around, I couldn't access the new changed APITeam getTeams function until I built the app.

Answer (score 2):

Change it to

```
func getTeams (leagueObjectID: String, onSuccess: @escaping(Any) -> Void, onFailure: @escaping(Error) -> Void)
```

Answer (score 1):

`static` might not work as you're used to in other languages. `static var` behaves like `class var`.

If I understand you correctly, this would satisfy your needs

```
@objc class APITeam: NSObject {
    private static let baseUrl = "http://api.website.com/api"

    private static let getTeamsEndpoint = "/teams"

    let params = "?season=last&league="

    private override init() {}

    func getTeam(id: String, _ onSuccess: @escaping(Any) -> Void, onFailure: @escaping(Error) -> Void) {
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: APITeam.baseUrl + APITeam.getTeamsEndpoint + APITeam.params + id)!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
            if let error = error {
                onFailure(error)
            } else if let responseData = data {
                do {
                    let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData)
                    onSuccess(result)
                } catch {
                    print(error)

                }

            }

        }.resume()

    }

}
```

Usage:
`APITeam().getTeam(id: "0Xc334xUK4", ..your completion handlers here..)`

Comment: As for how you _should_ do it, look into Alamofire. That's the most common HTTP wrapper for Swift.

Comment: The class that will use APITeam is written in objective C. Autocomplete doesn't seem doesn't show anything about the ID parameter declared in APITeam getTeams function: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ejq60e7gbn834m4/Screenshot%202017-12-13%2000.45.17.png?dl=0

Comment: Mark the function as @objc as well, then build the app once before attempting to access it. Seems to make Xcode generate the bridging header.

Comment: I was unable to call the APITeam getTeams method, so I used my original code with "sharedInstance". Building the app fixed the issue. I didn't realise I had to build in order to make it work. I assumed XCode would take of it automatically.

Comment: If my answer helped you resolve your issue, please mark it as accepted. Yeah, I've gotten stuck on that a couple of times. Never underestimate how useless Xcode can be ;P If building once doesn't do the job, it also helps to delete derived data, clean the project, clean the build folder and restarting Xcode. If that doesn't work either, try sacrificing a couple of lambs, then delete derived data and build again.